# How to change options of a select using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have an HTML page in which I have 2 `select`s.

```
<select id="field" name="field" onchange="checkValidOption();">
    <option />
    <option value="Plugin ID">Plugin ID</option>
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
</select>
<select id="operator" name="operator" onchange="checkValidOption();">
    <option />
    <option value="EQUALS">EQUALS</option>
    <option value="CONTAINS">CONTAINS</option>
    <option value="NOT CONTAINS">NOT CONTAINS</option>
    <option value="REGEX">REGEX</option>
</select>
```

What I'd like to happen is that `checkValidOption()` could make it so that if "Plugin ID" is selected in field that the only option is EQUALS (and it's selected) and otherwise all the other options are available.  Any idea on how to approach this?

I tried changing the `innerHTML` of the operator select in JS:

```
document.getElementById("operator").innerHTML =
    "<option value='EQUALS'>EQUALS</option>";
```

However this results in an empty `select` (this would also include manually setting the many `option`s for going back to having all the ones listed above).

I can't think of another solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read you comments and updated my code & demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YMXg/1/)

```
var field = document.getElementById('field');
var operator = document.getElementById('operator');
field.onchange = function () { fieldcheck(); }
operator.onchange = function () { fieldcheck(); }
fieldcheck();

function fieldcheck() {
    if (field.value == 'Plugin ID') {
        for (i = 0; i < operator.options.length; ++i) {
            if (operator.options[i].value != 'EQUALS') {
                operator.options[i].disabled = true;
            }
        };
        operator.value = 'EQUALS';
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < operator.options.length; ++i) {
            operator.options[i].disabled = false;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate options when `Plugin ID` was selected:

```
function checkValidOption(){
    var x=document.getElementById("field");
    var y=document.getElementById("operator");
    if (x.options[1].selected === true){
        document.getElementById("operator").options[1].selected = true;
        for(var i=0; i<y.length; i++){
            if (i !== 1){
                //disabling the other options 
                document.getElementById("operator").options[i].disabled = true;     
            }
        }
    }       
    else{
        for(var i=0; i<y.length; i++){
            //enabling the other options 
            document.getElementById("operator").options[i].disabled = false;     
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a **[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gB5Fc/2/)**

Comment: Your code is the closest to what I need (the ability to dynamically change what the available options are) but your for loops are throwing syntax errors (SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer) pointing at the initial assignment for i.

Comment: @avorum Sorry - had a bug :) now it's fixed - see updated code

Comment: Now I get "document.getElementById(...).options[i] is undefined

Comment: @avorum Check out the link I posted (against your code) - it's running fine, maybe you used an earlier version of my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

A select field doesn't use the innerHTML method, you need to use value.

```
document.getElementById("operator").value = "...";
```

Answer (score -3):

heres a jquery solution.

every time the first select changes, it produces new options from an array for the 2nd select. issue here is i had to change the option values of the first select to 0 and 1 to select which value in the array, you can manipulate those later if you are storing this info somewhere

http://jsfiddle.net/2TZJh/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#field").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#operator").html(options[val]);
    });
      var options = [

        '<option value="EQUALS">EQUALS</option>',
        '<option></option><option value="EQUALS">EQUALS</option><option value="CONTAINS">CONTAINS</option> <option value="NOT CONTAINS">NOT CONTAINS</option>        <option value="REGEX">REGEX</option>'

    ]; 

  });
```

Comment: whoever downvoted, care to explain why? It does exactly what OP asked. none of the other ones do...

Comment: I don't want JQuery, I want Vanilla Javascript.